# Retrieve image from folder

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm trying to access files from a folder and show the files which is representative for my search.

For example: my folder name is `images/example`.

That folder contains about 1223 files named `example_page (1)`, `example_page (2)` , `etc`.

In my url I have the following statement: `

```
www.example_url.com/example_page?book=example_book&chapter=example_chapter
```

A more specific url would be:

```
www.exampleurl.com/bible.php?book=genesis&chapter=2
```

The folder I mentioned earlier contains 1223 files from a book. What I want to do is to show the image(the page) specific to my url(book - genesis and chapter - 2). So, I want to access the image which contains the text genesis chapter 2. If my url parameter book is equal to genesis and chapter is equal to 2 then I want to access images/example folder and retrieve the file which contains the text Genesis 2.

Comment: Hasn't this already been asked today?

Comment: What have you got so far? Do you get any errors? Wrong images? How are images related to `book` and `chapter`, do you have a relation set somewhere? How would your script know what to load when your images are named `example_page (1)` etc.?

Comment: So combine the book and chapter value you got from the script URL, into the file name format (plus suffix), and then check if a file by that name exists in the folder ...? (You will probably want to try and avoid passing `genesis` and having the spelling inside the file name be `Genesis` though, because that would cause trouble in any case-sensitive file system.)

Comment: Oh, okay thanks a lot. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

i think u need view on ur web some fotos u uploaded to it.

if it is

use "/" before to path
"images/example." keep before as like this "/images/example."
and full image path /images/example.jpg or /images/example.gif

u need find ur .php file have where and since then image folder have where...
if not enough for ur q ask again...